# Saved passwords disappeared

Tags: google-chrome, passwords

Suddenly all my saved passwords are gone... If I go to 'Manage Passwords' in Chrome the list is blank.

However, if I visit https://passwords.google.com and login, my passwords are listed.

I am now having to copy / paste them to login to websites... but also I no longer get prompted to save my password when logging in or when changing my password

Comment: Please review https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6197437?hl=en in particular `Manage offers to save passwords`  as well as https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/165139?hl=en  in particular `Choose what info is synced`

Comment: also make sure your Chrome is still logged in with your Google account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is Sync turned off on the device in question?

I recently deleted all my passwords (Cookies, and so on) from my son's PC, and was supposedly signed out so it was only supposed to do this on that machine, not across all devices.

Luckily I had a PC that is only used every couple of weeks that hadn't synced.

I turned the WIFI off, went in to chrome Password Manager, then settings, then exported all passwords to a csv file. I was then able to import these to the machine that was online and hit sync and all is restored.

Comment: Yep, same happened to me. Definitely something buggy with it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after updating Chrome on my Mac yesterday.  All saved username and passwords disappeared from password manager, but were still all there in `passwords.google.com`. And saved info was not autofilling for login to any websites.  Spent hours searching the internet for a solution to no avail.

Then I resorted to restarting my laptop, and suddenly password manager  was intact again upon restart, and website login autofill was working again as usual.